# Modify response headers in Chrome Extension manifest v3

Tags: google-chrome-extension, browser, http-headers, content-security-policy, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I build an extension for Chrome, and need to modify [`Content-Security-Polity`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP) response header of any website in order to be able to inject JavaScript loaded the from remote host, so I need to add my host to [`script-src`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/script-src)

In manifest v2 I was able to do this with `webRequestBlocking`, but it seems to not work anymore in v3. Instead we must use [declarative NetRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/declarativeNetRequest).

However it supports only 3 operations: `append`, `set`, and `remove`. I can use `set`, but in this case I will just overwrite the website's original CSP header, which would be a security risk.

Ideally, I want to use regexp replace in response header, but how can I do it in manifest v3? Any ideas?

P.S. I'm aware that Chrome Web Store policy doesn't allow to run remote code. This extension is built for internal use only, and will be installed manually (not via Chrome Web Store)

Comment: There's no solution via DNR, so you'll have either to remove this header entirely or stop injecting the script or use webRequestBlocking by patching Chrome or starting it like chrome --allowlisted-extension-id=YOUR_EXTENSION_ID. Actually the best solution for now is to keep MV2 version until a new API to modify CSP is implemented.